# Text To Speech (TTS) delays by 3 seconds to speak text

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I am using the TextToSpeak feature in my android app and realized its taking up some delay before speaking out the actual word.

```
onCreate(){
 textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
            }
        }
    });

 textToSpeech.speak("Hello World", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
 performAction();
}

performAction(){…}
```

As you can see I am then calling the performAction method immediately after using TTS .speak() method, but the 3 second delay causes some inaccuracy.

How can I trigger the performAction method to be called immediately the word is spoken out.

Comment: TextToSpeech.speak() is asynchronous.  I'm surprised that you're hearing anything since you're calling speak() before the textToSpeech object has initialized.  What TextToSpeech engine are you testing with?  Are you going to call speak() inside onCreate() in the actual app or will it be triggered by  button press, or some other event?  You can use UtteranceProgressListener to trigger performActionEvent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the most efficient way of doing it,I had a similar problem to this and used a Handler to solve it.

```
onCreate(){
  textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new 
  TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
            textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
        }
    }
  });

  textToSpeech.speak("Hello World", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
  checkIfTTSIsSpeaking();
}

checkIfTTSIsSpeaking() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      if(textToSpeech.isSpeaking()){
         performAction();
      }else{
         checkIfTTSIsSpeaking();
      }
     }
    },10);
}


performAction(){…}
```

TextToSpeech engine has a method `isSpeaking()` which returns a boolean whether or not the word is being spoken.

[TextToSpeech reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#isSpeaking())